# Looking for a way to view an interpolated query in golang mysql

Tags: go

So, I have a reasonably complicated query which I am trying to debug, but for a simple example let's say I have something like this:

```
q := "SELECT id FROM users WHERE timestamp > ? AND timestamp < ?"
```

I will do a Query() on this the usual way, e.g.

```
db.Query(q, 1546300800,1561127488)
```

And I would like to log/println/whatever (for debugging) the interpolated query, to end up with

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE timestamp > 1546300800 AND timestamp < 1561127488
```

Wondering if anyone has a trick for me here.

Comment: Not in Go as it does not do the interpolation, both the query string and the argument values are sent to the db server, which does the interpolation. So if the db server doesn't provide such a feature then you're out of luck. Alternatively you could try searching for a 3rd party package that does the interpolation, however if you find one keep in mind that to be accurate it needs to keep up with the target server's version, if it doesn't do that you may see logs that don't match the actual query being executed.

Comment: Ahh that explains a great deal thank you.

Comment: I guess I should point out that the above is entirely dependent on the driver that you're using, however, no sane driver would elect to do the interpolation themselves since then they would also have to implement protection against sql injection and who knows what else to match server's functionality. And again, for the driver to be useful it would need to keep up with the server's updates. So in case you find such a driver, one that does its own interpolation and sql-injection protection, I'd recommend you do not use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @mkopriva's comments,

> Not in Go as it does not do the interpolation, both the query string and the argument values are sent to the db server, which does the interpolation. So if the db server doesn't provide such a feature then you're out of luck. Alternatively you could try searching for a 3rd party package that does the interpolation, however if you find one keep in mind that to be accurate it needs to keep up with the target server's version, if it doesn't do that you may see logs that don't match the actual query being executed

I cannot accomplish this using tooling, as go never has the interpolated query. Sticking to spitting out the non-interpolated query along with the pile of arguments.